# Access network share from IIS hosted WCF web service

Tags: wcf, networking, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a C# WCF web service hosted by IIS7 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. My web service needs to access a network share and so during Application_Start I execute the following:

```
NETRESOURE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
nr.dwScope = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
nr.lpRemoteName = string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", MyServer, MyShareName);
nr.lpLocalName = @"X:";
string UserName = MyWebSvcLoginName;
string Password = MyWebSvcPassword;
uint result = WNetAddConnection2(ref nr, Password, UserName, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE);
```

This has been working fine for 3 months. All of the threads in the web service process had access to the mapped drive. Now, all of a sudden, only the thread that called WNetAddConnection2 has the drive mapped. I am not aware of anything that changed in the server configuration. Are there any options that would prevent other threads in the process from seeing the mapped drive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the difference between what works and what does not. Things to check are:

- Does the one that works running in a different application pool with a different identity. Has the identity that does not work lost some rights?
- Does the one that works use a different user name and password to access the share. Has the passord of the user that does not work expired?
- Do all map to the same drive letter? Is the drive being used for another share?

Comment: This is a total mystery. I have 2 production servers and 1 development server. The problem started a week ago on the development server. All app pools are exactly the same. All servers use same exact credentials and drive letter to map the share. The problem started on one of the production servers today after the app was recyled due to a config change (increased startup timeout). Password used is set to never expire.